# After updating IDEA, it suddenly requires to change package name

Tags: intellij-idea

Today I updated IntelliJ IDEA to the latest version because it notified me. But after updating it, now it starts to consider `main/java` as package folder as well, so every class is now causing same problem about package.

[image]

Of course I can just move folders one by one... But is there any way not to do this? Is moving folders the only solution? Picture below is current version of my IDEA. Also, is there any reference about this changes? Why did they decide to make IDEA recognize `main/java` as package folder?

[image]

Comment: Maybe projects settings are off, try right clicking on the java folder and setting it as a source folder.

Comment: Fix your content roots, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, as you suggested, just setting source root fixed problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I noticed that one of my existing gradle project automatically changes folder structure like this after clicking `Build Project` button. Project in question was maven project, and for some reason, source root was set as `src`, not `java`.

I remember still, setting `src` as source root was also fine before updating, but for now, setting `java` folder as source root fixed problem

[image]